# 'npm start' is not executing what is has to preform

Tags: angular

I'm entering the command `npm start` and it fails.
Please help
see the log:

`PS C:\Users\PAZ\Desktop\Angular-GettingStarted-master> npm start`

```
> npm ERR! path
> C:\Users\PAZ\Desktop\Angular-GettingStarted-master\package.json npm
> ERR! code ENOENT npm ERR! errno -4058 npm ERR! syscall open npm ERR!
> enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
> 'C:\Users\PAZ\Desktop\Angular-GettingStarted-master\package.json' npm
> ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file. npm
> ERR! enoent
> 
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> 
> npm ERR!    
> C:\Users\PAZ\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-06-24T21_45_01_011Z-debug.log
> PS C:\Users\PAZ\Desktop\Angular-GettingStarted-master>
> 
> PS C:\Users\PAZ\Desktop\Angular-GettingStarted-master> npm start npm
> ERR! path
> C:\Users\PAZ\Desktop\Angular-GettingStarted-master\package.json npm
> ERR! code ENOENT npm ERR! errno -4058 npm ERR! syscall open npm ERR!
> enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
> 'C:\Users\PAZ\Desktop\Angular-GettingStarted-master\package.json' npm
> ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file. npm
> ERR! enoent
> 
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!    
> C:\Users\PAZ\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-06-24T21_45_01_011Z-debug.log
> PS C:\Users\PAZ\Desktop\Angular-GettingStarted-master>
```

Comment: Have you ensured there's a `package.json` file in the directory you're running the command and it has a `start` script?

Answer (score 1):

package.json doesn't exist in the current folder, if you are using this project 
https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-GettingStarted :

you need to run the `npm start` from ***APM-Start*** folder